# How do I replace atributes of XML file by using shell scripting sed command?

Tags: xml, bash, shell, ionic-framework, sed

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
...
</widget>
```

How can I replace id and version in widget by using sed?

Comment: Don't use sed to process XML files. Use an XML-aware tool.

Comment: I have a constraint of using inbuilt functions. As i will be running it in multiple servers

Comment: Talk to the people who set the constraints. They make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sed is not the correct tool to handle XML, as the attributes might appear in different order and or different lines while still keeping the same semantics.

Use an XML aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) currently maintained by me), you can just write

```
open file.xml ;
register-namespace w http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets ;
set /w:widget/@id "new.id" ;
set /w:widget/@version "0.0.2" ;
save :b ;  # :b creates a backup.
```

Comment: I need to achieve this without installing any dependencies..is it possible..??

Comment: It depends on what's already installed. There are many similar tools, e.g. XMLStarlet, even xmllint has some limited capabilities.

Comment: fresh linux.. and the order will always be same

Answer (score 1):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit -N x='http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets' \
                --update "//x:widget/@id" --value "foo" \
                --update "//x:widget/@version" --value "bar" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="foo" version="bar">
...
</widget>
```

If you want to edit file inplace, add option `-L`.

Comment: how change email and href and value in this line <author email="hi@xyz" href="http://example.com/">Author name</author>

Comment: @rakshans1: I recommend to start a new question and indicate if you are using namespaces (`xmlns="..."`) in your XML file.